# Push notification not working after changing bundle id

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Push notification was working fine until I **changed bundle Id**. After changing bundle Id app fails to register remote notification and it calls `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` method each time.

I came to know that push notification stopped working because I changed bundle id. But don't know what change I need to do to make it working again. Do I need to change bundle Id somewhere else or any other solution? I don't have any idea because push notification was done by other person.

Please answer with steps and detail as I am not aware of these stuffs.

Comment: did u change the provisioning profile?

Comment: have you enabled Push Notifications for your new bundle id?

Comment: @manujmv No I did not do anything. Actually that is the point that I don't know what to do. I'm afraid of breaking other stuff and that's why asking for what to change. Btw, you mean I need to create provisioning profile? Do I need to created new App id with new bundle Id?

Comment: @Nandha In my apple account I don't have my bundle id. Can I edit my old bundle id to new one?

Comment: @Akash To create provisioning profile for your app, your bundle id and app id should be unique. So create a new app id as same as your new bundle id and enable push notification for that id. To know more, Please http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1. in that check "Making the App ID and SSL Certificate"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not try Marius' answer but you should first try that. What I did is started from scratch and followed all steps on [Push Notification Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to solve my problem.

Comment: I think you post this question just to get ranked. Listen If you have to update the app. The developer like will prefer to build a new app instead of using the previous version code. :P

Answer (score 2):

Go to [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/), click on **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** > **Identifiers** . Here you have to create the new app id to match your new bundle id. Enable push notifications and then go to **Provisioning Profiles** section, find your app provisioning profile and update it (Click edit and choose your new app id) or create the new one. Push notifications should work with this provisioning profile.

Comment: Will this new app id be app id of app store? I mean I use app id in my app, so will I need to change it to use new one?

Comment: Nop, App Store application id is different thing. App Id in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers section will be used when you will create provisioning profile and when you will submit your app to the App Store. P.s. If this app is already in the App Store, you need to know that after bundle id change you can't update existing application.